# simply way to increment

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("a[rel=example_1],a[rel=example_2],a[rel=example_3],a[rel=example_4],a[rel=example_5],a[rel=example_6],a[rel=example_7],a[rel=example_8],a[rel=example_9],a[rel=example_10]").fancybox({............
```

Hello, right now I have to manually enter those codes.

Is there an easy way to increment the numbers?

I know I can use something similar to `a[rel=example_[1-10]]`. What is the correct syntax?

many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One potential solution would be to use a loop.

```
var element = 'a[rel=example_';
var elements = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    elements.push(element + i.toString() + ']');
}

elements = elements.join(', ');

$(elements).fancybox()
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to match all elements with a `rel` *containing* "example_", you can use an attribute selector like this:

```
$('a[rel*="example_"]').fancybox()
```

Finally, you could simply use a class to link all of the elements and select them by referencing the common class.

Comment: thank you for your answer, both two ways seemed dont work for fancybox. neither $('a[rel*="example_"]').fancybox({.........}) or use var method. Is that fancybox problem?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
a[rel^="example_"]
```

This will select all `a` elements that have a `rel` attribute that begins with "example_". I'd recommend this over loops if you want to select all the elements that match that pattern.

Answer (score 5):

If it's ok for you - you could go with

```
$('a[rel^="example_"]').
```

and it will match all `a` that have `rel` started with `example_`

Otherwise - use fine-filtering for it:

```
$('a[rel^="example_"]').filter(function() {
    var match = $(this).prop('rel').match(/^example_(\d+)$/);
    return match.length == 2 && parseInt(match[1]) <= 10;
})
```

The callback for the `.filter()` explicitly checks if there is a number `1..10` after underscore

Answer (score 2):

use a for or while loop. Each time it iterates add one to a counter variable or if you use a for loop it will do that by itself.

heres some pseudocode:

```
var output

for count 1 to 10:

output .= $("a[rel='example'" + count];

next for
```

Answer (score 1):

You could select all the element that start with "example_" using this selector:

```
$('a[rel^=example_])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a string to be used as a query:

```
var query = [];
for(var i=1;i<=10;i++)
    query.push('a[rel=example_' + i + ']');
$(query.join(',')).fancybox({});
```